# System freezes for a couple seconds when pressing the forward slash "/" key in a Corsair Vengeance K90 keyboard on Ubuntu based distros

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, freeze

So, when I'm type the forward slash key, the whole system freezes for a couple seconds.
This is only happening with my Corsair K90 keyboard.

What I've got so far:

1. Using another keyboard (Logitech MK120), the freezing does not happen.
2. The freezing happens when using Ubuntu and Pop_os. It does not happen on Windows, Manjaro XFCE and Fedora.
3. Using a different USB, the freezing still occurs.
4. Switching the keyboard layout, the freezing still occurs.
5. Using a different computer, the freezing still occurs.
6. Both the keyboards use the ABNT2 layout (brazilian portuguese)

So, it looks like the freeze only happens with my Corsair K90 and on Ubuntu based distros.

## syslog

#### Ubuntu

```
Apr  1 16:58:05 ubuntu gnome-shell[5525]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
    
Apr  1 16:58:05 ubuntu gnome-shell[5525]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
    
Apr  1 16:58:05 ubuntu gnome-shell[5525]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
    
Apr  1 16:58:05 ubuntu gnome-shell[5525]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
    
Apr  1 16:58:05 ubuntu gnome-shell[5525]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
    
Apr  1 16:58:05 ubuntu gnome-shell[5525]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
    
Apr  1 16:58:05 ubuntu gnome-shell[5525]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
    
Apr  1 16:58:05 ubuntu gnome-shell[5525]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
    
Apr  1 16:58:05 ubuntu gnome-shell[5525]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
```

#### Pop_OS

```
Apr  1 14:39:37 pop-os gnome-shell[3511]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 71 with keysym 71 (keycode 18).
```

## xev

Typing /asd, I've got:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 1566707, (279,55), root:(2394,314),
    state 0x10, keycode 97 (keysym 0x2f, slash), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

MappingNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248

KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 1566746, (279,55), root:(2394,314),
    state 0x10, keycode 39 (keysym 0x73, s), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (73) "s"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (73) "s"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 1566790, (279,55), root:(2394,314),
    state 0x10, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 1566822, (279,55), root:(2394,314),
    state 0x10, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 1566840, (279,55), root:(2394,314),
    state 0x10, keycode 39 (keysym 0x73, s), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (73) "s"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 1566874, (279,55), root:(2394,314),
    state 0x10, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

## xmodmap

Using the command `xmodmap -pke | less` I got:

```
...
keycode  97 = slash question slash question degree questiondown degree questiondown slash question degree questiondown
...
```

I tried removing some repetitions with the command `xmodmap -e "keycode 97 = slash question degree"`, but that did not help.

## Testing with another keyboard (Logitech MK120, no freezing)

### xev

Typing "/asd". The "MappingNotify event" does not seem to occur with this keyboard, and the freezing does not happen.

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 1907488, (155,-8), root:(2120,101),
    state 0x10, keycode 97 (keysym 0x2f, slash), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 1907576, (155,-8), root:(2120,101),
    state 0x10, keycode 97 (keysym 0x2f, slash), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 1907592, (155,-8), root:(2120,101),
    state 0x10, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 1907640, (155,-8), root:(2120,101),
    state 0x10, keycode 39 (keysym 0x73, s), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (73) "s"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (73) "s"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 1907720, (155,-8), root:(2120,101),
    state 0x10, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 1907728, (155,-8), root:(2120,101),
    state 0x10, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 1907784, (155,-8), root:(2120,101),
    state 0x10, keycode 39 (keysym 0x73, s), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (73) "s"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x1e0, subw 0x0, time 1907824, (155,-8), root:(2120,101),
    state 0x10, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

What can I try next to stop the freezing from happening with the Corsair keyboard?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, what version of Ubuntu? e.g. Ubuntu_Studio_20.04 LTS. And unofficial solution: https://forum.corsair.com/forums/topic/107444-unofficial-linux-osx-driver/

Comment: Now I'm using Pop_os 21.10, but I've tried Pop_Os 20.04 and Ubuntu 20.04. 
Strangely enough, in Fedora, which also uses Gnome, this didn't happen.

Comment: I installed the Cosair driver as you've suggested, and that seems to have fixed it! Can you post as an answer so that i can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citation of Corsair forum: https://forum.corsair.com/forums/topic/107444-unofficial-linux-osx-driver/

Install the unofficial driver. (it may help.)

Answer (score 0):

I've got a Strix Keyboard with Swiss layout (QWERTZ) on Fedora 37.
The backslash (ALTGR+<) resulted in a similar freeze.

Disabling NKRO (N-Key rollover) solved the issue (Press FN+PGUP to toggle on/off)